# Tuckey URL: Redirected url is outputted twice

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter, redirect

I have the following redirect in place:

```
<rule>
    <condition name="host" operator="equal">^(www.)?test.redirect.com$</condition>
    <from>^?</from>
    <to type="redirect" last="true" encode="true">http://www.redirect.com/test/test-123</to>
</rule>
```

It does redirect, however it redirects to `http://www.redirect.com/test/test-123http://www.redirect.com/test/test-123`.  Does anyone know why it is outputting twice like that?

As a side note I want to add that it is NOT being redirected twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<from>` clause was incorrect:

```
<rule>
    <condition name="host" operator="equal">^(www.)?test.redirect.com$</condition>
    <from>^(.*)</from>
    <to type="redirect" last="true" encode="true">http://www.redirect.com/test/test-123</to>
</rule>
```